# Issue with letter spacing in a justified GIMP text block

Tags: gimp, text

I'm working with a block of text in GIMP that consists of three short paragraphs, which are full-justified in their text box. The first paragraph seems to be perfectly fine; spacing between words automatically adjusts so the lines of text are distributed evenly across the width of the box. But in the second paragraph, you can clearly see how some of the spacing has increased between *individual letters* instead of the full words. The issue is also present in the third paragraph, though not as severe.

I've messed with all the text settings (not that GIMP has a super robust text editor in the first place) and have tried increasing and decreasing letter spacing, all to no avail. I also tried manually adding spaces to try to even everything out, but that ends up doing more harm than good.

This image is obviously just using placeholder text, but my actual project is behaving the exact same way: perfectly fine first paragraph, totally screwed up second paragraph, and so-so third paragraph. Does anyone know what the problem is, or how to fix it? I've worked with justified text in GIMP plenty of times and have never run into this spacing issue.

I'm running version 2.10.30 if that matters.

**EDIT:** I had someone in another forum suggest that the font itself could be the problem. Unfortunately, this font is required for branding purposes so there's no escaping it. Is there truly no way to force the lines to balance out the way they do in the first paragraph?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't reproduce the problem. Sorry.  Have you tried changing the font? If other fonts work, then that may suggest a problem with the font.

Comment: @BillyKerr What I ended up doing was exporting my project (minus the text) as a JPG and loading it up in Photoshop instead--for some reason, the text justification worked perfectly fine in PS, so I'm not sure if the font was the problem (or if it was, it was just a problem in GIMP). This font is required for branding purposes anyway so I'm stuck with it :/

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. What Gimp version? Are all these one single paragraph or did you force line feeds? Also Gimp isn't a text formatter, if you have so much text, you should investigate using a typesetting application (Scribus or else).

Comment: @xenoid per the original post, I'm running version 2.10.30. This was originally 3 paragraphs within 1 text box, but I had someone in another forum suggest making 3 separate text boxes to see if they would all turn out fine like the first paragraph. That seemed to work.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with several files created in an older version. The files have text boxes that are justified with Calibri. When the files load, the text displays correctly. When I try to select text, the gold boxes do not line up with the letters. If I make any changes to the text at all (delete, font size, etc.), the letter spacing is ruined and cannot be repaired, even with the undo button.

I should note that each textbox has different font stylings within it (e.g., some text is bold, underlined, smaller, etc.). But I did not have problems editing these files previously.

Comment: Exact same problem.... Using 2.10.30
Will have to abandon all idea of justified text !

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. The justification is perfect in the first paragraph but everything is spaced out randomly for the other ones. I have to do separate paragraphs to make it work. I was wondering if a previous version of Gimp would fix this.

Comment: @ROY21 I was actually just talking to someone about this yesterday and they mentioned they did have an older version that still worked correctly. I don’t know which version or how old, but that’s at least useful to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solutions.

1. With version 2.10.32 I had the same exact problem, and was fixing it by using a separate text box for each paragraph.
2. I just reinstalled 2.10.28, and the problem seems to be gone. No need to use separate paragraph boxes.

Answer (score -1):

go back to 2.10.24 for now. I just did that and text justified works